# Minimize $x^2y^2z^2$ using classical inequalities.

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Minimize $x^2y^2z^2$ if $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

Well I want to minimize it using classical inequalities; because I have easily maximized it with $AM\ge GM$ as follows:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2 z^2}$$
$$\iff 4 \ge3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2 z^2} \iff \frac{4}{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{x^2 y^2z^2}$$
$$\iff \frac{64}{27}\ge x^2y^2z^2$$
but I don't know how to find the minimum using classical inequalities. Is there a way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are $ x,y \geq 0$? If yes, the min is clearly 0. If no, then what you've shown is $5 \geq |xy|$ so $ xy \geq - 5 $ and you are done (just have to keep track of signs).

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh! Thanks

Comment: @CalvinLin I have edited the question because I was trying to solve this question with the same method of the answer of the earlier question and it didn't work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=0$ and $y=z=\sqrt2$.

Thus, $$x^2y^2z^2=0$$ and since $$x^2y^2z^2\geq0$$ for any $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, we got a minimal value.

Id est, $$\min_{x^2+y^2+z^2=4}x^2y^2z^2=0.$$

Comment: $+1$. The obvious way. Fine.